# Существует ли способ менять CSS стили без JS?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Всем привет, подскажите, каким образом можно поменять CSS стили или добавить HTML элементу атрибут без использования JS?

Comment: Существует - вручную изменить код страницы в любимом текстовом редакторе. Какая у вас задача и в чём суть вопроса?

Comment: А в какой ситуации он должен меняться, если логику не запрограммировать?

Comment: Суть задачи в том, чтобы менять размер и цвет div при нажатии на кнопку. Использовать js нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуй, Дмитрий. Крайне странный вопрос и крайне странная задача.

Не нашел возможности изменение стиля с помощью button, но есть вариант с checkbox, который выглядит следующим образом.

```css
.switch {
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 5%;
    transition: all 2s ease;
}


.change:checked ~ .switch {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="forum.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" class="change">
    <div class="switch">
        Я меняюсь
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Надеюсь, помог вам с вашим вопросом.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло